# Mapping child items of same class with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm trying to map a fairly "standard" category model using EF Code First

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public List<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

I've got something along the lines of:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
    .HasOptional(t => t.ParentCategory)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.ParentCategoryID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

But this doesn't seem to take care of ChildCategories??

Am I missing something?

To avoid the duplicate question argument, I followed the following, however didn't quite answer my specific query:

[Code First Mapping for Entity Framework Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064591/code-first-mapping-for-entity-framework-hierarchy)

[Entity Framework CTP5 Code-First Mapping - Foreign Key in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146013/entity-framework-ctp5-code-first-mapping-foreign-key-in-same-table)

Comment: What do you mean by "But this doesn't seem to take care of ChildCategories??"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your Entity to

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> ChildCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Make `ParentID` nullable and to allow `ChildCategories` to be lazy loaded, make it virtual.