# EF 4.3 code first mapping N:M on same type

Tags: .net, orm, entity-framework-4, many-to-many, ef-code-first

I am trying to map a many to many scenario with objects of the same type.

So i have a parent object of MyType with many children of the same type. Also an object of MyType can have many parents. How do you do this?

I looked at [Mapping child items of same class with Entity Framework Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351381/mapping-child-items-of-same-class-with-entity-framework-code-first) but it is not the same issue (child has only one parent)

Comment: Please provide your dbcontext class

Comment: It's empty, besides a `Set<MyType>`. Also, the MyType class is empty, besides an Id property. What is missing is the `ICollection<MyType> Children` and the `ICollection<MyType> Parents` properties, because i dont know how to correctly map them within the same type. I always end up with too many FKs in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a mapping entity in between, so i now have 1:n:1 mapping