# Trouble with EF code first relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Ok, this should be simple but I am having trouble.  I have two classes Region and Location.  A region can have many locations but a location can only be in one region.  Simple stuff.    Here is what I have:

```
Location             Region 
---------            -------
int LocationID       int RegionID    
string Name          string Name
string BlahBlah      List<Location> Locations
string OtherStuff
int RegionID
Region Region
```

Now I need to add a home office to a region.  The home office is also a location.  Entity Framework seems confused so I am obviously doing the wrong thing.  This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Location             Region 
---------            -------
int LocationID       int RegionID    
string Name          string Name
string BlahBlah      List<Location> Locations
string OtherStuff    int HomeOfficeID
int RegionID         Location HomeOffice
Region Region
```

What am I missing here?

In case you don't like what I wrote above here are the classes:

```
 public class Region
{
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public int HomeOfficeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Location HomeOffice { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

 public class Location
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }              
    public int RegionID { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would argue that in most domains `HomeOffice` is likely more than just a location, Although a location may be one of its properties.

Comment: Even so that would not solve the circular foreign key dependency.

Comment: I suppose it might be made easier if I had a HomeOffice class that had Region and Location properties.

Comment: Can you post some code with this? I think what you are asking is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351381/mapping-child-items-of-same-class-with-entity-framework-code-first But without knowing what your code or the error you are getting is, it is hard to know how to help. The question I link is slightly more complex than what you are asking.

Comment: He did put his code up...just in a stupid database like format. He could have just give us the C# code first classes..

Comment: The classes would help - e.g. are the `Locations` and `HomeOffice` both virtual in Region?

Comment: There is not much more to the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if the "home office" really has no other data than any other location, there's a workaround:

```
Location             Region 
---------            -------
int LocationID       int RegionID    
string Name          string Name
string BlahBlah      List<Location> Locations
string OtherStuff
int RegionID         
Region Region
bool IsHomeOffice
```

Now, Region gets a read-only property:

```
public Location HomeOffice
{
    get { return Locations.FirstOrDefault(l => l.IsHomeOffice); }
}
```

You'll also need some validation code to ensure that you don't end up assigning more than one Location to IsHomeOffice, but this will get you started.

EDIT: Comments have made me realize this approach doesn't allow a HomeOffice to be located outside of the Region is is located in.  Could that happen?  First thought is unlikely, but perhaps "HomeOffice" really means where HR staff for a region is located.  Right now the HomeOffice is always inside the region, but in the future that Company could decide to do HR for a region remotely.  In this limited example it wouldn't be too painful to adapt, but as your data model gets more complex it can become more painful when the structure of your data model needs to change. Instead of always relying on the structure to enforce rules, consider keeping the structure flexible and adding data validation on entry.

Comment: This would imply that Home Office locations are not reusable. May be a valid assumption.

Comment: @Mathew This seems reasonable to me, otherwise a location could be the HomeOffice for a Region it doesn't belong to.  That wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Also did you delete something from the code?  I thought that Region had int HomeOfficeLocationID or something like that.  In our use the home office location will always be in the same region the location is actually in.

Comment: @georgewillow Yes, I did remove the HomeOfficeId, as it's not necessary because that implies a foreign key relationship.  But you can always call Region.HomeOffice.LocationID if you need that data.  The post should also have an edited <time ago> notice below it, which you can click to view the revision history.