# Mapping a self-join to a collection in code first entity framework 4.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.3

I have a POCO class that maps to a self-joined table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GalleryCategories](
    [CategoryID] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[GalleryCategories] ([CategoryID]) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION, 
)
```

I know there's a way to define a relationship using the model builder to reference a parent from a child... (e.g. [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146013/entity-framework-ctp5-code-first-mapping-foreign-key-in-same-table))

But the class I'm trying to map looks like this...

```
public class GalleryCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Subcategories { get; set; }
}
```

In other words, I'm trying to get Subcategories populated with all of the children - i.e. traverse down the hierarchy, not up the hierarchy.

Is there any way to do this using EF?  This must be a FAQ somewhere but I couldn't find it after googling for an hour :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should that be a List Subcategories in your class?  If so, and it's a self referencing table, you can create the mapping either way Data Annotations like this:

```
 public class GalleryCategory
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? ParentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
        public virtual List<GalleryCategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
    }
```

or in Fluent like this:

```
 public class Model : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<GalleryCategory> Categories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<GalleryCategory>()
               .HasMany(x => x.Subcategories)
                .WithOptional()
                .HasForeignKey(g => g.ParentID);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mark - remarkably, the fluent code is character for character exactly the code I tried, and it works nicely.
I initially tried the [ForeignKey()] attribute but it didn't compile in 4.3... There appears to be an [Association] attribute that I thought I could use to accomplish the same thing, but I wasn't able to get that to work.  Do you know what [ForeignKey] has been renamed to?

Comment: One more comment... I can get linq queries to work well - e.g. GalleryCategories.Include("Subcategories.Activities").Include("Activities").Where(c => c.ParentID == null).  However, when I try to Add a new GalleryCategory which has Subcategories, EF throws a foreign key relationship exception (basically it won't automatically fix up the Subcategories' ParentID to what the GalleryCategory got assigned by the server).  Do I need to do something special in the mapping to make this scenario work, or is it just a limitation of EF and I have to "manually" do the recursive add?

Comment: Can you post the details to this in a new question?  Be sure to include the entire call you're making.  EF should be able to make the connections by simply adding to the navigation properties.