# Displaying related data from the same table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I think I'm having a senior moment, but I also think I have not run into this situation before. I have two columns in my MVC5 Identity 2.1 `Users` table.

```
UserId | BannedBy (and also an IsBanned bool)
```

Both fields are userid guid strings. However, BannedBy refers to a different user in the same Users table.

When I display my view of banned users (a table and each row is one banned user), I don't want to show the BannedBy guid, I want to show the related  UserName for that BannedBy guid. However, I can't seem to figure out what I need to do.

I've tried a ViewModel and method approach:

```
public ActionResult BannedUsers()
    {
        var bannedUsers = db.Users.Where(d => d.IsBanned);

        var model = new BannedUsersViewModel
        {
            BannedUsers = bannedUsers,
            BannedByUserName = GetUserName(bannedUsers.BannedBy)
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

Then like an outer approach to my viewmodel:

```
var model = new BannedUsersViewModel
        {
            BannedUsers = bannedUsers
        };
        model.BannedByUserName = GetUserName(model.bannedUsers.BannedBy);
```

However, it seems I can't use the bannedUsers.BannedBy (I also tried all that above with a capital B... BannedUsers.BannedBy) data before it's actually been rendered? And now I've scrapped the viewmodel and am trying to do like a related data join on my query:

```
db.Users.Join(d => d.BannedBy == d.UserId).Where(d => d.IsBanned);
```

(I'm sure this is way off, I'm just trying to give you an idea)

Does anyone know the proper way of doing this? I was also thinking about calling a method from my view, but seems like that would be breaking the MVC rules?

Thank you.

Update: Here is the GetUserName method:

```
public string GetUserName(string userId)
    {
        var result = db.Users.Find(userId);

        return result.UserName;
    }
```

Update #2: Here is the BannedUsersViewModel:

```
public class BannedUsersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> BannedUsers { get; set; } 
    public string BannedByUserName { get; set; }

}
```

Update #3: A pic:
[image: BannedUsers]

Comment: Can you also show extended user entity and its mapping? Because you need to configure self join In Users Entity

Comment: Well, if `BannedUsers` is a list of users that have been banned then wouldn't `BannedByUserName` really need to be a list of users that have banned these users?  I get the impression that `GetUserName` takes a single `Guid`.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @Jason Boyd Yes, you are correct. GetUserName just does a fetch on the db.Users table using the guid. I'll edit my post to include that. I'm still digesting the other thing you wrote...thanks.

Comment: @lazy Thanks, I'm not real sure what you're asking. You mean show my Identity model for how I extended it? In my IdentityModels.cs I simply added `public string BannedBy { get; set; }` under `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`. Googling self join now...

Comment: @Jason Boyd Imagine a table of banned users, each row is one banned user. One of the columns in the table is BannedBy and right now I'm looking at a guid, when I want to be looking at a username. So, I'm not sure how a list of BannedByUserNames would relate to that? Thanks.

Comment: Oh okay. Here you go a stackoverflow answer on self [referencing entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975727/mapping-a-self-join-to-a-collection-in-code-first-entity-framework-4-3)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a stab at this.  We can modify it as needed (unless I am completely off base, in which case, I will delete this and we will all pretend it never happened).  Does this get you in the ballpark:

```
public ActionResult BannedUsers()
{
   var bannedUsers = 
        db.Users
        .Where(d => d.IsBanned)
        .Join(
            db.Users,
            bannee => bannee.BannedBy,
            banner => banner.UserId,
            (bannee, banner) => new BannedUser() 
                { 
                    BannedByUserName = banner.UserName,
                    BannedUser = bannee 
                })
        .AsEnumerable();

   var model = new BannedUsersViewModel
   {
       BannedUsers = bannedUsers
   };

   return View(model);
}

public class BannedUsersViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<BannedUser> BannedUsers { get; set; }
}

public class BannedUser
{
    public ApplicationUser BannedUser { get; set; } 
    public string BannedByUserName { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that we get all of the banned users, join them to all of the users that banned those users and then group by the user that banned them.  You end up with a collection of objects that have the user that banned other users and the users they banned.

Comment: Sounds promising and looks brilliant. However, I'm getting a AnonymousType conversion error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,AnonymousType#2>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProjectSender.Models.ApplicationUser>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)` Even when I pass bannedUsers straight to the view (minus the viewmodel), it gives a similar error. I tried changing my viewmodel BannedUsers to IQueryable<ApplicationUser> and it doesn't like that either. Any ideas? Thanks again...

Comment: I added the BannedUsersViewModel above... :)

Comment: You need to modify your `BannedUsersViewModel` no matter what solution you come up with.  It is not logically sound as it is.  Users in `BannedUsers` could have been banned by any number of different users; which of those names would you use for `BannedByUserName`.  Let me update with a full example of how I would approach it.

Comment: Try changing your view model. Instead of IEnum<appuser>, have an IEnum of an object that has the columns you want in your table.

Comment: Actually, a user can only have been banned by one user (either an admin, or a moderator) as the option to ban is only visible to those roles. So it will only ever be one guid for the bannedby Id (since once a user is banned they are no longer visible to anyone except on this page above). This page will be for admins to correlate between banned users and possible admins/mods that may be ban "happy." It will also allow Admins to unban people, but I already have all that worked out. I just have this one last piece to the puzzle. I'm open to other suggestions... I'll try what you suggested..Thanks

Comment: It's starting to look like I should have just used username instead of the guid in the first place... BUT... we're considering allowing users to change their username... so that's the reason for using the guid...

Comment: I understand that a single user can only be banned by another single user.  But given any set of banned users some of them could have been banned by modA and some of them by modB.  Which of the two would you use for `BannedByUserName` in your current viewmodel design?

Comment: If that were possible, it would only overwrite the field with whomever was the last one to click the ban button. Keep in mind, I'm not using claims, I've just added a BannedBy column of type string to my Users db.

Comment: If userA is banned by modA and userB is banned by modB then both userA and userB would be in `BannedUsers`.  Given your current viewmodel, whose name would be used for `BannedByUserName`?  modA or modB?

Comment: Correct that they would both be part of `BannedUsers`. So, when the table is put to the view, row one would be userA and show modA (currently the guid) in the BannedBy column. UserB would be row two and show modB in the BannedBy column. So each row of `BannedUsers` is a different banned user and that row contains the guid for the person that banned them.

Comment: So essentially, my View is nothing more than a snapshot of my Users table where IsBanned is true. The View is the standard View that is created with the wizard. The viewmodel and all the rest has simple come into play in trying to convert this BannedBy guid to a username.

Comment: It compiles without error, but I'm getting this in the browser: `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ProjectSender.Models.BannedUsersViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ProjectSender.Models.ApplicationUser]'.` I tried changing my @model statement in my VIew and a couple other things with no joy.

Comment: I added a pic to the original question so you can see the original result. I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I went with @lazy's comment in doing a self join. I'm not sure how good I feel about it though. So essentially, I added this to my IdentityModels.cs under `public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser`:

```
[ForeignKey("BannedBy")]
public virtual ApplicationUser BannedByUser { get; set; }
```

Then in my controller, changed my original query to a list:

```
var bannedUsers = db.Users.Where(d => d.IsBanned).ToList();

return View(bannedUsers);
```

(If I don't convert to list, it complains about having more than one data reader open.) Then in my View in my foreach loop:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BannedByUser.UserName)
```

And boom:
[image: Banned Users]

I'm a little worried of the performance impact?...especially for a page that isn't used that often and is not really that important. Is there an impact if the page isn't being called (like with the Index that was created and such)? I'm also a little leery since there seems to be some magic happening with Identity.

Anyway, I'm still open to other ideas...or thoughts about this one. Thanks again for everyone's help.